# What can I use instead of an update trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have an update trigger in SQL Server and I want to remove this trigger and make update operation with a stored procedure instead of the trigger. But I have `UPDATE(end_date)` control in update trigger.

What can I use instead of below `UPDATE(end_date)` control? How can I compare old and new end_dates in stored procedure efficiently?

Update trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_tbl_personnel_car_update] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_personnel_cars]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
    IF (UPDATE(end_date))
        UPDATE pc
        SET pc.owner_changed = 1
        FROM tbl_personnel_cars pc, inserted i
        WHERE pc.pk_id = i.pk_id
```

Sample updated script in stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[personnel_car_update]   
    (@PkId INT)
    UPDATE tbl_personnel_cars 
    SET end_date = GETDATE()
    WHERE pk_id = @PkId
```

I update `tbl_personnel_cars` table inside many stored procedures like this. How can I update this table like trigger does instead of update trigger?

I tried below codes to get old and new `end_dates` but I can't.

Sample updated script in stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[personnel_car_update]   
    (@PkId INT)
    UPDATE tbl_personnel_cars 
    SET end_date = GETDATE()
    WHERE pk_id = @PkId

EXEC update_operation_sp_instead_trigger @PkId
```

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_operation_sp_instead_trigger]   
    (@PkId INT)
    UPDATE pc
    SET pc.owner_changed = 1
    FROM tbl_personnel_cars pc
    JOIN tbl_personnel_cars pc2 ON pc.pk_id = pc2.pk_id
    WHERE pc.end_date <> pc2.end_date
```

And last question. Is it a correct choice to use stored procedure instead of trigger where the table is updated?

Comment: Stored Procedures and Triggers aren't really comparable, if I am honest. So asking is it "correct" isn't really an answerable question. The *real* answer is that you should be using the right object appropriate for the task at hand.

Comment: *"What Can I use instead of below UPDATE(end_date) control? How can I compare old and new end_dates in store procedure efficiently?"* I hate to tell you this, but you do know that `UPDATE(end_date)` doesn't check if the *value has changed*, right? `UPDATE(<Column Name>)` checks if the column appears in the `UPDATE`'s `SET` clause, *not* if the value changed. `UPDATE (SomeColumn)` would return true for statements like `UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET SomeColumn = SomeColumnl` or `UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET SomeColumn = 1 WHERE SomeColumn = 1;`, even though not a single value was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I want to clarify a misunderstanding you appear to have about the `UPDATE` function in Triggers. `UPDATE` returns a boolean result based on if the column inside the function was assigned a value in the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE` statement. It **does not** check if that value changed. This is both [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) feature, and is stated to be "by-design".

This means that if you had a `TRIGGER` with `UPDATE(SomeColumn)` the function would return TRUE for **both** of these statements, even though no data was changed:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = SomeColumn;

UPDATE ST
SET SomeColumn = NULL
FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
WHERE SomeColumn IS NULL;
```

If, within a `TRIGGER`, you need to check if a value has changed you need to reference the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables. For non-`NULL`able columns equality (`=`) can be checked, however, for `NULL`able columns you'll also need to check if the column changed from/to `NULL`. In the latest version of the data engine (at time of writing) `IS DISTINCT FROM` makes this *far* easier.

---

Now onto the problem you are actually trying to solve. It looks like you are, in truth, overly complicated this. Firstly, you are setting the value to `GETDATE` so it is almost certainly *impossible* that the column will be set to be the same value it already set to; you have a 1/300 second window to do the *same* `UPDATE` twice, and if you add IO operations, connection timing, etc, that basically makes hitting that window twice *impossible*.

For what you want, just `UPDATE` both columns in your procedure's definition:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[personnel_car_update] @PkId int AS --This has a trailing comma, which is invalid syntax. The parathesis are also not needed; SP's aren't functions. You were also missing the AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.tbl_personnel_cars  --Always schema qualify
    SET end_date = GETDATE(),
        owner_changed = 1
    WHERE pk_id = @PkId;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Larnu gave you a great answer about the stored procedure logic, so I want to answer your question about "Is it a correct choice to use stored procedure instead of trigger where the table is updated?"

The upsides of DML triggers are following in my opinion:

1. When you have a lot of places that manipulate a table, and there need to be some common logic performed together with this manipulation like audit / logging, trigger can solve it nicely because you don't have to repeat your code in a lot of places
2. Triggers can prevent "stupid" actions like: DELETEs / UPDATEs without WHERE by performing some specific validation etc. They can also make sure you are setting all mandatory fields (for example change date) when performing adhoc updates
3. They can simplify quick and dirty patches when you can concentrate your logic to one place instead of X number of procedures / compiled code.

Downside of triggers is performance in some cases, as well as some more specific problems like output clause not working on the triggered tables and more complicated maintenance.

It's seldom you can't solve these issues with other non-trigger solutions, so i'd say if your shop already uses triggers, fine, but if they don't, then there's seldom a really good reason to start either

Comment: You are right, I already have a trigger but this trigger cause some performance problems so We decided to do what the trigger does where the table is updated. Any other advice on removing the trigger and doing what it did?